# Chai.js compare arrays without considering order

Tags: javascript, chai

What I'd like to do is compare 2 arrays of primitives using chai.js, but without considering the order of elements - like if they were 2 sets.

Now obviously I can do something like this:

```
const actual = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const expected = ['b', 'c', 'a'];
expect(actual).to.have.length(expected.length);
expected.forEach(e => expect(actual).to.include(e));
```

But I'm curious if there is a prefered 'built in' way of doing this (I couldn't find it in the docs).

Comment: without the order it's tricky in arrays... your code should be able to differ `["a", "b" ,"c" ,"b"]` and `["a", "c", b", "c"]`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the built in check ['members'](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members):

`expect([4, 2]).to.have.members([2, 4])`

Comment: Very good, thanks, this is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: This does not rule out superfluous elements, so it technically does not answer the question. This is why I gave -1 here.

Comment: For an array of objects, `to.include.deep.members()` works.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach that is not true, or at least not in the current version of chai. From the linked docs: "By default, both arrays must be the same size. Add .include earlier in the chain to require that the target’s members be a superset of the expected members."

Comment: I am not sure whether this changed during chai updates. But `expect([1, 2, 2]).to.have.members([1, 1, 2])` is still an edge case uncovered by the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Answers above `expect([4, 2]).to.have.members([2, 4])` won't check the size as author mentioned about.
`expect([1,2,2]).to.have.members([1,2])` will pass the test.

The best option is to use https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/deep-equal-in-any-order/

Comment: You can additionally assert that the length matches. Which ensures that exactly the members you expect are in the array.

Comment: @Narretz , yes and It requires one extra check, so deep equal in order is one raw instead of two or extra code .and

Comment: That is not the case, at least not in the current version of Chai. From the docs (https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members): "By default, both arrays must be the same size. Add .include earlier in the chain to require that the target’s members be a superset of the expected members."

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [members assertion](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members) from chai BDD.

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var should = require('chai').should();

let a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let b = ['c', 'a', 'b'];
let c = ['d', 'e', 'c', 'b'];

describe('test members', function() {
    it('should pass', function() {
        a.should.have.members(b);
    });

    it('should fail', function() {
        a.should.not.have.members(c);
    });
});
```